# Is the sample mean of the gradient the same as the gradient of the sample mean?

Tags: expected-value, calculus

By the law of large numbers, given a continuous random vector $\mathbf{x}$, then:

$$
\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{x}] \approx \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \mathbf{x}_i
$$

Where $\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2,...,\mathbf{x}_N$ are sampled from $p(\mathbf{x})$. By the law of the unconscious statistician:

$$
\mathbb{E}[f(\mathbf{x})] \approx \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} f(\mathbf{x}_i)
$$

Now let $\theta$ be a vector of non-random parameters, such that $g(\mathbf{x};\theta)$ is some function of the random vector $\mathbf{x}$ and the parameters in $\theta$. Can I then approximate the following expectation:

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\partial g(\mathbf{x};\theta)}{\partial \theta}\right]
$$

Like this?

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\partial g(\mathbf{x};\theta)}{\partial \theta}\right] \approx \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{\partial g(\mathbf{x}_i;\theta)}{\partial \theta}
$$

If I can, then is it accurate to say that:

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\partial g(\mathbf{x};\theta)}{\partial \theta}\right] \approx \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left(\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} g(\mathbf{x}_i;\theta)\right)
$$

In other words, the sample mean of a gradient is equal to the gradient of the sample mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The derivative and expectation have the associative property (you can exchange the order) by [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) (computing the expectation is just some sort of integration)

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \int_{a}^{b} f(x,\theta) d\,x = \int_a^b \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} f(x,\theta) d\,x$$

(Note that not every operation has this property and you can have $f(E(X)) \neq E(f(X))$)

Comment: +1. So this holds even before the approximation, i.e. $E[\triangledown_\theta(g(\cdot))]=\triangledown_\theta(E[g(\cdot)])$, where $\triangledown$ is the gradient. So then the approximation inside  $\triangledown()$ follows directly from the LLN, assuming $\textrm x$ is $iid$. I think of $g(x,\theta)$ as a random variable itself (since it depends on a rv), hence for the LLN, LOTUS is not even needed here. Also, an example for $f(E[\cdot]) \ne E[f(\cdot)]$ (which holds most of the time, equality is an exception) is with $f(x)=x^2$.

Comment: Ah, now I see that you were thinking about the [continuous mapping theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem). That is indeed not necessary for this case. But that theorem works for every function.