# Does the approximation of the gradient of the log-likelihood imply the approximation of the log-likelihood?

Tags: likelihood, gradient

Let $ln(p(\mathcal{D};\theta))$ be the log-likelihood function, such that $\mathcal{D}=\{\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2,...,\mathbf{x}_N\}$ is the observed data and $\theta$ is a vector of parameters. Now suppose that:

$$
\frac{\partial \ ln(p(\mathcal{D};\theta))}{\partial \theta} \approx \frac{\partial g(\mathcal{D},\theta)}{\partial \theta}
$$

Where $g$ is a function that maps $\mathcal{D}$ and $\theta$ to a scalar in $\mathbb{R}$. Is it accurate to then say that:

$$
ln(p(\mathcal{D};\theta)) \approx g(\mathcal{D},\theta)
$$

Comment: Can you at least *link* to your earlier question, and explain what is new here?

Comment: Are you referring to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/499152/is-the-sample-mean-of-the-gradient-the-same-as-the-gradient-of-the-sample-mean) one? If so, the only thing common between them is that they involve gradients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we integrate this equation from some arbitrary $\theta_0$ to $\theta$, we get:
$$\frac{\partial \ln(p(\mathcal{D};\theta))}{\partial \theta} \approx \frac{\partial g(\mathcal{D},\theta)}{\partial \theta}\Rightarrow \ln p(\mathcal D;\theta) - \ln p(\mathcal D;\theta_0) \approx g(\mathcal D,\theta) - g(\mathcal D,\theta_0)$$

If we define $C=\ln p(\mathcal D;\theta_0)-g(\mathcal D,\theta_0)$, we have $\ln p(\mathcal D;\theta)\approx g(\mathcal D,\theta)+C$. That means that $\exp[g(\mathcal D,\theta)]$ is approximately proportional to the likelihood.

This is a very informal discussion, if we want to get more specific here we would need more information about the meaning of "$\approx$". Are the gradients asymptotically equal? Are they close in some region of the parametric space only? Can we describe this approximation in terms of big-O or something like that?

Anyway, I believe it's safe to say that $g(\mathcal D,\theta)$ is an approximation of $\ln p(\mathcal D, \theta)$, up to an additive constante.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed response! Actually, could you check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3931833/approximation-of-the-gradient-of-a-log-likelihood-function-implies-the-approxima) question that I asked over at math.SE? I go into much more detail there. I would really appreciate it if you could comment on the reasoning over there. By the way, this is related to the gradient of the log-likelihood for a Restricted Boltzmann Machine.

Comment: @mhdadk I answered on math.SE. I do not know much about Restricted Boltzmann Machines, but I could answer it from a mathematical perspective